# If $a-\sqrt{2021a} = 1$, find $a-45\sqrt{a}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, roots

If a is a positive real number such that $$a-\sqrt{2021a} = 1$$ evaluate $$a-45\sqrt{a}$$
I've factored the $2021$ into $43\cdot 47$ and then $(45+2)(45-2)$ so $$a -\sqrt{(45^2-2^2)a} = 1$$ but I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: The $2021$ seems a little bit suspicious. Where is this problem from?

Comment: Its a HW problem from a competition math class from this local math place called RSM.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the equation gets really really messy when plugging "a" back so is there any other (perhaps slick?) way to do this?

Comment: As first stated, the second $a$ is *not* under the radical, but in your reformulation it *is* under the radical. They can't both be right...

Comment: Got it, sorry about that... the "a" should be under the radical.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t = \sqrt a$. Then, $$a - \sqrt{2021a} = 1$$
becomes $$t^2 -  \alpha t - 1 = 0$$
where $\alpha^2 = 45^2 - 4$. Solving this for $t$, we get
$$t  = \frac{\alpha  \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4}}{2} = \frac{\alpha \pm 45}{2} \tag{*}$$
We take only $"+"$ from $"\pm"$ since $t > 0$.

Now, we need to find the value of $t^2 - 45t$.

We subtract $45$ from both sides of $(*)$, to get $$t - 45 = \frac{\alpha - 45}{2}$$ Multiply by $t$:
$$t^2-45t = \frac{\alpha - 45}{2}t = \frac{\alpha - 45}{2}\frac{\alpha + 45}{2} = \frac{\alpha^2 - 45^2}{4} = \frac{-4}{4} = -1$$

Answer (score 1):

VIVID's solution is complete. Here is a solution in other words. By rearranging and squaring the equation we have:

$$(a-1)^2 = 2021a = (45+2)(45-2)a = (45^2 - 2^2)a$$
Therefore:
$$45^2a = (a-1)^2 + 4a = (a+1)^2 $$
And recalling that $a$ is positive (and so $a>-1$) we have:
$$45\sqrt a = a+1$$
Therefore:
$$a - 45\sqrt a = -1 $$